# Terminate actual spring web flow execution

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

is it possible to determine the actual running flow in a spring mvc context and terminate it ?

The reason why I'm asking is, that in my shop web app the whole checkout process is a web flow but the header menu is still visible and now I experience the problem that if a menu link is klicked the flow is exited but I don't recognize it.

I hope it is understandable what I want and I appreciate any help to get through this issue :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly - you wanted to terminate the current flow but still have the menu click work - is that right?

If it is, have a global common flow that is inherited by all your subflows. Then, add this in the `flow` tag of each of your flows, where `commonFlow` is the name or ID of your global flow definition file.

```
parent="commonFlow"
```

In this global flow definition, define the transition for the menu option:

```
<global-transitions>
<!-- If Menus are triggered on flows, we end them first. -->
<transition on="menuClick" to="endCurrentFlowThenMenu"/>
</global-transitions>
```

And then define a redirect for the menu:

```
<end-state id="endCurrentFlowThenMenu" view="flowRedirect:menuView"></end-state>
```

However, this only works when current flow is a parent/top-level flow. If it is a subflow, it gets a little bit dirty - you need a work-around so that all subflows are ended first:

```
<global-transitions>
<!-- If Menus are triggered on flows and subflows, we end them first. -->
<transition on="menuClick" to="endCurrentFlowThenMenuLevel1"/>
    <transition on="endCurrentFlowThenMenuLevel1" to="endCurrentFlowThenMenuLevel2"/>
</global-transitions>
```

In which case you define the matching end states:

```
<end-state id="endCurrentFlowThenMenuLevel1" view="flowRedirect:newFlow">
</end-state>
<end-state id="endCurrentFlowThenMenuLevel2" view="flowRedirect:newFlow">
</end-state>
```

The reason why I repeat the `view` attribute on each end state is so that it could still work even if the current flow is a top-level flow. Depending on the maximum deepest subflow, you need have multiple transitions and end states to match them (i.e. if you max deepest functionality can have 2 subflows, repeat the above 3 times).

The trick here is, if the current flow is already a top level flow, SWF would not bubble up the parent and will just execute the `flowRedirect`.

If, however, the current flow is a subflow, SWF will not execute the redirect on the subflow, but instead will bubble up to the parent first, looking for a matching transition for the current subflow that just ended. It would continue doing this until it finds the top-level flow in which case it would execute the redirect, effectively ending all subflows in the process as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible share global transition between flows and subflows, the way to do it's similar to above code.

Basically, you must define an abstract flow,**commons-headers**, setting *abstract=true* inside flow tag, then to define *global-transitions* which will be share among flow/subflow, these global-transitions can redirect to some kind of event, in this example to *end-state*.

Calling flow define, **main flow**, define *subflow-state* tag, here you must write returned transition from called flow,**subflow**, which must be the same *id* shared between *transition* and *subflow's end-state tag*, this is the way to finish subflow and return to the main flow. If you wish use some global transitions then you must define these transitions inside *subflow-state* tag setting same value for *main flow's on* attribute and *global-flow's to* attribute (in this example will be loginEnd and signEnd). Last step, *main flow's to* attribute must coincide with some *global flow state id* attribute (in this example loginEnd and signEnd again).

**Commons-headers**

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
abstract="true">

<end-state id="loginEnd" view="flowRedirect:login" />

<end-state id="signupEnd" view="flowRedirect:signup" />

<global-transitions>
    <transition on="login" to="loginEnd" />
    <transition on="signup" to="signupEnd"/>
</global-transitions>
```

**Main flow**

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
    parent="commons-header">


<view-state id="inicio" view="main.xhtml">
    <transition on="manageSpace" to="adminSpaces" />

    <transition on="goSpace" to="visitSpace" />
</view-state>

<subflow-state id="visitSpace" subflow="space">
    <on-entry>
         <evaluate expression="space.showSpace(requestParameters.idSpace,flowRequestContext)" result="conversationScope.visitedSpace" />
    </on-entry>

    <transition on="finishSubFlow" to="inicio" />

    <transition on="loginEnd" to="loginEnd" />
    <transition on="registerEnd" to="registerEnd" />
</subflow-state>

<end-state id="error" view="flowRedirect:error" />
```

**Subflow**

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
parent="commons-header">


<view-state id="showPicture" view="space_pictures.xhtml">

    <on-entry>
         <evaluate expression="multimediaProvider.showPages('picture')" result="viewScope.pagesList"/>
     </on-entry>

    <transition on="goMain" to="finishSubFlow" />
    <transition on="visit" to="visitPicturePage" />
</view-state>

    <view-state id="visitPicturePage" view="show_picturePage.xthml">
        <on-entry>
            <set name="flowScope.code" value="requestParameters.code" />
        </on-entry>
        <on-render>
             <evaluate expression="multimediaProvider.loadPage(flowScope.code)" />
        </on-render>

        <transition on="goMain" to="finishSubFlow" />       
    </view-state>

<end-state id="finishSubFlow" />
```